# Detect single mouse click in PyQt5 Widgets - missing mouseClickEvent function

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5

I would like to recognize a single mouse click over a `QWidget` in PyQt5. In the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html) there is either `mouseDoubleClickEvent` or `mousePressEvent` but there is no `mouseClickEvent` function for a single click. How do I get that functionality? Thank you

BTW I've noticed PyQtGraph does have a [`mouseClickEvent`](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graphicsscene/mouseclickevent.html) function.

Comment: With "click" do you mean press *and* release?

Comment: I mean a press that is released at the same place.

Comment: There's also `mouseReleaseEvent`. If you're aiming on detecting a single mouse click, this might be an option

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Qt doesn't provide a "click" event on its own, you have to implement such a feature based on `mousePressEvent` and `mouseReleaseEvent`, by checking that the release has happened within the geometry of the widget (and, possibly, that the correct mouse button was pressed and released).

```
class ClickWidget(QWidget):
    pressPos = None
    clicked = pyqtSignal()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.pressPos = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        # ensure that the left button was pressed *and* released within the
        # geometry of the widget; if so, emit the signal;
        if (self.pressPos is not None and 
            event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and 
            event.pos() in self.rect()):
                self.clicked.emit()
        self.pressPos = None
```